# When to use JFace ComboViewer instead of combo?

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

In my application I need two combo boxes, the content of second one depends on the current selection of first combo. Should I use JFace ComboViewer for this? or shall I directly use combo?

If I use JFace ComboViewer what flexibility I'll get? or how JFace ComboViewer is better than Combo?

For more clarity, I have to use only strings for my combo.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary difference - as far as I am concerned - is the use of a `ILabelProvider` for `ComboViewer`, whereas you have to calculate the entries yourself for `Combo`. Whether to use one or the other depends on the specific use-case...

Comment: I have to use only strings for my combo...so what should I do?

Comment: Then use a `Combo`. It is only when you need to generate the strings from objects, you should need a `ComboViewer`.

Answer (score 1):

Combo is just the widget, ComboViewer wraps that so you use a model other than just strings.  You rarely want to create and interact with plain widgets directly.

Comment: I have to use only strings for my combo...so what should I do?